# nicematrix and tikz external/optimize

Tags: tikz-external, nicematrix

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450841/tikz-externalize-and-nicematrix-package) the nicematrix v3.3 (2019/10/01) package from @f-pantigny has no problems with the tikz tikzexternalize library.

But this code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    $
        \begin{pNiceArray}{CCCC|C}
        \star   & \circ     & \Cdots    & \circ     & \circ \\
        0       & *     & \Ddots    & \Vdots    & \Vdots    \\
        \Vdots  & \Ddots    & \Ddots    & \circ     &       \\
        0       & \Cdots    & 0         & 0         & \circ 
        \end{pNiceArray}
    $
    \tikz\draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
\end{document}
```

don't compile (TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)) with the error

> Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e

The externalize logfile has the lines

```
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to d
isable this.

! Package nicematrix Error: A dotted line can't be drawn because you have not
(nicematrix)                put all the ampersands required on the row 3.
(nicematrix)                If you go on, this dotted line will be ignored.
```

If we use

```
\tikzexternalize[optimize=false]
```

then everything compile.

Is this a bug and if yes, why?

@f-pantigny: Maybe a fix is to add at line 586 from nicematrix.sty

```
external / optimize = false
```

Comment: I wouldn't add it to the `.sty`, for sure. Somebody might prefer not to externalise `nicematrix` environments and keep optimisation. Hard-coding it in the `.sty` would confuse things. Maybe something in the documentation would be better or an option.

Comment: @cfr I agree with your objection but one could add something like `\ifcsname tikzexternal@TEXDIALECT@collectpicture\endcsname \endcsname% <do something>\fi` to make sure that this will only be executed if externalize is loaded. It might also be better to turn off optimization only locally, i.e. within the `nicearray` environments.

Comment: @cfr nicematrix enviroments are not externalize per default (line 586 from nicematrix.sty). I mean to disable optimization only locally for the nicearray environments.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think that my suggestion turn off optimization for the nicearray environments, didn't it?

Comment: Sorry if it already did! I have not checked carefully.

Comment: It might work better disabling externalisation for the picture rather than just setting `export` to `false`. I've found that the latter isn't always enough. Sometimes, only the former will do.

Comment: I will try to find the best solution... (I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a new version of `nicematrix` (v. 3.4 of 2019/10/05). In this version, the optimisation of the externalisation of Tikz is disabled in the environments of `nicematrix` when the package or the class `standalone` is used.

Comment: @f-pantigny thanks for the fast update. I tested it and it works (for me).